# Parse HTML with Regex and C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I've HTML code like this:

```
<tr class="discussion r0"><td class="topic starter"><a href="SITE?d=6638">Test di matematica</a></td>
```

I need to only select "Test di matematica" and I think to do this with Regular Expression.
I tried with:

```
 string pattern= "<tr class=\"discussion r0\"><td class=\"topic starter\"><a href=\"" + site + "=d{1,4}\"" + ">\\s*(.+?)\\s*</a></td>";
```

but it doesn't works.. what I can do for selecting words after expression and before other expression?

EDIT: Can you tell me how can I do with HTMLAgility to parse this string?
Thanks.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack... And close...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Is totally impossible? 
With this:
     
     string patternTitolo = "d=\\d{1,4}\">\\s*(.+?)\\s*</a></td>";

works a little..

Comment: @user3579313 It is "misguided" and "fragile". HTML should not be parsed with regular expressions - it's a gross hack with an inappropriate tool applied when there are existing solutions.

Comment: So I can't use MatchCollection?

Comment: @user3579313 Sure you can. However, this doesn't fix the fundamentally broken design of trying to use a regular expression for this task. I would *reject* (and I have before) any such code that uses regular expressions and/or manual string manipulation to deal with HTML or XML (or JSON or ..).

Comment: Anyway, `=d{1,4}` is clearly wrong, and I don't feel like wading through the rest of it.

Comment: Watch for my edit pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex makes sure that the text we capture is inside an `<a` tag which is inside a `<td` tag which is inside a `<tr` tag.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program {
static void Main() {

string s1 = "<tr class=\"discussion r0\"><td class=\"topic starter\"><a href=\"SITE?d=6638\">Test di matematica</a></td>";
var r = new Regex(@"(?i)<tr[^>]*?>\s*<td[^>]*?>\s*<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string capture = r.Match(s1).Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(capture);
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**The Output:** `Test di matematica`

Comment: Pls, can ou tell me how can I edit you regex in order to capture text only inside a tag <tr> </tr>?
I'm trying with (?i)<tr[^>]*?>([^<]*)</tr> but doesn't works...

Comment: @user3579313 `(?i)<tr>([^<]*)</tr>`

Comment: This is new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376687/regex-for-html-tr-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string myString = "<tr class=\"discussion r0\"><td class=\"topic starter\"><a href=\"SITE?d=6638\">Test di matematica</a></td>";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"<a.*?>(.*?)</a>");
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(myString);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Match match = matches[0]; // only one match in this case
    GroupCollection groupCollection = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine( groupCollection[1].ToString());
}
```

***DEMO***

http://ideone.com/nFY6aw