# Regex for HTML <tr> tag

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I have an HTML page with `<tr>` classes and I need to capture the text inbetween those tags.

I tried with `Regex`:

```
(?i)<tr[^>]*?>([^<]*)</tr>
```

But it doesn't work.

This is all my code in C#:

```
string patternPost = @"(?i)<tr[^>]*?>([^<]*)</tr>";
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, patternPost, RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match m in m1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Here you can find an example of HTML page: http://pastebin.com/ewN5NZis

You can see 2  block, I need to store for each of  blocks, three info in three different list:

```
List 1: Title1, Title2
List 2: John, Antony
List 3: 29/04/14, 28/04/14
```

With my first regex I wanna try first to catch all blocks and skip useless information like tags differents from **tr** and next I wanna try to catch 3 infos for each blocks with 3 different regex.
Is this right? I hope now you understand me.

Comment: [NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why not use the `XmlDocument` class?

Comment: As per @Jonesy's link, this is a **BAD IDEA**!

Comment: Please define doesn't work. For all the naysayers, regex is more powerful than it seems, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406). Ok it might not be maintainable for upcoming newbie-regex-reviewers but hey just add comments with the `x` modifier :)

Comment: So surprising that you are the very first person to write web scraping tool in C#... I seem to remember seeing similar question in the past - maybe you can try searching for it :)  Note that *the question* contains most of the possible approaches to reading HTML (including some theory of RegEx and HtmlAgilityPack link), so please make sure to read it past the top answer.

Comment: Doesn't works = empty string for all the html page..

Comment: @user3579313 it would be really helpful to add a fiddle, try [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) out. It's not C# specific, but I think it might be enough for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: In your last comment, you said: `<tr ....> <tag> ... </tag> <tag2>...</tag2> </tr>` which is quite an expansion on the original problem. At this stage, I concur with all other advice: you are going to need a dom parser.

Older Edit: Originally you asked to match contents of `<tr>` tags. Specs have changed, so this answer contains the evolving versions.

For a plain `<tr>` tag: extract Group 1 from

```
(?i)<tr>([^<]*)</tr>
```

or for a `<tr with stuff>`:

```
(?i)<tr[^>]*>([^<]*)</tr>
```

or for `<tr stuff><td stuff>Grab Me</td>`

```
(?i)<tr[^>]*?>\s*<td[^>]*?>(.*)</td
```

Here is a code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program {
static void Main() {

string s1 = "<tr stuff><td stuff>Grab Me</td>";
var r = new Regex("(?i)<tr[^>]*?>\\s*<td[^>]*?>(.*)</td");
string capture = r.Match(s1).Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(capture);
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Output: `Grab Me`

Comment: No, I think the problem is that into <tr> tag there are a lot of other tags so my code doesn't works..

Comment: @user3579313 Please see the second part of the solution that I just added. :)

Comment: Is equal to my code on first post :)

Comment: @user3579313 Please give me an example of a full tag that is not matching.

Comment: @user3579313 Please see my "Grab Me" regex just added for your new specs.

Comment: @user3579313 Also updated C# code sample to get "Grab Me"

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem is that into my html code with <tr> tag I have a lot of other tag, so I must specify all the tags?

Isn't possible to capture all text between <tr ....> <tag> ... </tag> <tag2>...</tag2> </tr>? I need to capture tag too, all text, tags included, between tag <tr> and </tr>..

Comment: @user3579313 Hmm... Please see my latest edit at the top. That is as far as I can go with it.

Comment: Sorry but you don't understand me... I edited my first post with a screen shoot of html page, I need ALL the row between the <tr> and </tr> includes all other tags.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @user3579313 If you give me a test string I can directly copy and paste, I can do a test. I also need you to tell me exactly what you are trying to match. Some people use websites where you can paste a code sample.

Comment: I edited my first post (hope for the last time :) ).